# Techniques for keeping iOS NSTimers from being killed in background

Tags: objective-c, ios, timer, multitasking

Relatively new to obj-c and iOS but I've created a little app that is built around 4 simple, stopwatch-style timers. The user starts up a timer, it starts counting and they go on with their life. When they open up the app they can see how long it's been going. Individually, these timers would be identical to the one in the Apple Clock app.

This works "most" of the time. I've had timers running for days, started, stopped, reset, started up again. What I've noticed though is that if the app is pushed just a little too far down the multitasking drawer, the next time I open up the app all my timers will be at zero, and the app will be in it's freshly launched state.

To me this appears related to the OS thinking my app is not needed, killing its threads/processes/whatever to free up memory. For the apps intended audience, it will be a frequently checked app so this may not crop up as a problem, but it seems that there should be some technical approach to ensure that my stopwatches never fail. I'm just not sure where to look for this kind of functionality. Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You are doing it wrong.

If you build a stopwatch app with 10 timers you need exactly one NSTimer.
And this timer refreshes the display. This timer is not needed when the app is in background.

NSTimers have the problem that they can be late, and they should not be used to schedule time critical stuff (like counting a second up).

---

Store the current NSDate when you start a timer and display the difference in the app.

Store those NSDates to NSUserDefaults and they will even survive a restart of the device.

Comment: ... and if you're looking for a timer to refresh the display, `CADisplayLink` is probably smarter than an NSTimer.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I was obviously misinterpreting the actual use of an NSTimer. Storing start date and calculating from their only when the app is foreground makes good sense. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach: For your "timers" keep track of the start time only, and for display purposes calculate the number of seconds since the start time and display accordingly.

Store these start times so that even if the app is "evicted", you'll still know when a timer was started and can calculate how much time has elapsed.

The only reason to use an NSTimer would be if you want to show the timer's seconds ticking by.

Also have a look at the delegate methods `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`. In these methods you'd want to invalidate and re-establish an NSTimer (if you're using one), respectively.

There is a lot of Apple documentation about what you can and cannot do in the background [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I do actually want to show the "seconds ticking by" as you said, but obviously that's meaningless when the app is in the background. Guess I need to rethink that structure. I assumed NSTimer should be used for, ya know, timing things. :)

Comment: Heh. Well, you will be timing something: The update of the display, which, as you observed, isn't important if the app is in the background or not running. You don't actually have to count the seconds with a timer running. You can just calculate how many seconds went by since the start. Much more efficient. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to ensure that your app will continue to run in the background the way you want it to.

You can use `-beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` to request up to ten minutes of additional execution time but in all likelihood your application will be terminated.

I've heard an Apple engineer refer to this as 'evicting'.

Comment: Boo on the drive by. Comment at least if you think something is worth that. Lame. Thanks for the input. I played with Apple's Clock app, and that one seems very persistent. I started up a stopwatch, and even killing the app manually out of multitasking will bring it up with the timer still going and in the right spot. Hmm.

Comment: That is strange.  Sorry I can't help you more.  Aside: Apple applications probably don't play by the same rules as user-submitted application, so I wouldn't use Apple's app as a reference.