# Ideal way to make NSTimer fire in the background, and check that it is still firing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, nstimer, nsthread

I have gotten a NSTimer to fire a selector every second correctly. However, I require  it to continue firing even when it goes into the background. I have even tried the jailbreak tweak called Insomnia, which supposedly stops apps from sleeping in the background, but to no avail. So what would be the best way to achieve my objective?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Techniques for keeping iOS NSTimers from being killed in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274926/techniques-for-keeping-ios-nstimers-from-being-killed-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

There are only certain things you can do as background tasks in iPhone apps.  The [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) explains how it works and what you can do. The apps that use some of the background features don't continuously run - they are woken at 'appropriate times'.

Comment: So am I correct in saying the only way to achieve this, even on a jailbroken phone, is to entirely keep the app from sleeping when its backgrounded? I read somewhere that you can request an additional 10 minutes of runtime before the OS kills the app in the background.