# Allow timers to fire when applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have read Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and as many posts as I could here on the topic of how an app can run once it has been backgrounded.  It seems that there are ways to get an application to complete some remaining tasks but not continue to run indefinitely in the background.

My app has timers set to go off so audio clips can be played to the user.  What happens is once the app is backgrounded the clips are not played.  I know this can be done somehow as I have run a couple apps like what I am trying to do that are handling it.  One example being: [Nike+ GPS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nike-gps/id387771637?mt=8)  Are these apps just never calling endBackgroundTask?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Techniques for keeping iOS NSTimers from being killed in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274926/techniques-for-keeping-ios-nstimers-from-being-killed-in-background)

Comment: That topic is similar but he wanted to keep an accurate time once the application is made active again.  In my case I want to have my application become active when a timer goes off or give me periodic updates so I can check my timers.  It seems the only long term method is by making the app gps, voip, or audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some scenarios where your App can run in the Background.

Check: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

- audio. The application plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)
- location. The application keeps users informed of their location, even while running in the background.
- voip. The application provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.

Comment: I think this might be my answer.  I.e. it is only possible in the above cases and in the specific case of Nike+ GPS they are using GPS and that is waking up the application all the time.  Is a GPS enabled app allowed to do other tasks during a GPS update?  I am guessing that is how it is being done.

Comment: I added UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities - location-services and now my app runs how I want.  So the above scenarios are the only ones to get an app to run indefinitely in the background.  The app will drain the battery, especially because users might not know to kill the app after they are done using it.  I should add a quit button it seems.

Comment: And if you want to get this app on the appstore, you need a good reason to do background work.

Comment: yes, there is no doubt.  I assumed that was understood but shouldn't have.  I did have a mapping screen but wasn't planning on doing much with it until I ran into this issue.